# Добавление индикатора загрузки при старте приложения

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, как правильно добавить индикатор ожидания(например небольшое окно с прогресс баром) на время загрузки основного окна приложения, на какие события или методы стоит обратить внимание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 появился класс SplashScreen, объявленный в сборке WindowBase. Не знаю как с анимацией, а просто картинки он показывает без проблем.

Использование: в проект приложения (не библиотеки, а именно запускаемого exe-шника) включается картинка. В свойствах файла задаём BuildAction=Resource. После этого имя файла передаётся в конструктор класса SplashScreen и вызывается метод Show.

Подводный камень: SplashScreen блокирует модальные диалоги, появляющиеся перед открытием главной формы. Для того чтобы этого не произошло, нужно перед показом диалога явно закрыть SplashScreen.